# How can i install annotation and profiler for an old version of Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, composer-php

When I try to install annotations or profiler for Symfony 4

> composer require annotations
>
> composer require --dev profiler

he install  using version 5 and I get this problem

[image]

**note : i dont want to upgrade to  version 5.
i am good with version 4.0.13**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `:version` end of your commands and for example use this commands:

```
composer require annotations:1.7.0

composer require --dev profiler:1.0.3
```

And see which version is true for your symfony version:

> https://github.com/doctrine/annotations/releases
>
> https://github.com/symfony/profiler-pack/releases

Comment: space is also legit composer require annotations 1.7.0

Comment: i used composer require annotations:1.7.0 and it say [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package sensio/framework-extra-bundle in a version matching 1.7.0

Comment: Use another version